# Querying on arrays with jpql in hibernate 6.1

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql, jpql

In hibernate 6.1, we can now map Lists or Sets to database arrays. the mapping is working fine my question  is there any support for querying on the arrays?

in my entity, I have a field like this

```
class A {
Set<Integer> lists;

}
```

i want to query like this

```
"select a from A a where :ele member of lists";
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for this yet. You can follow https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/discussions/5562 though to receive updates on this matter.